# Test Classes in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, test-class

I have an assignment that looks like this:

> Write a class called `Animal` with a default `sound()` method. Create child classes with the `sound()` method for the following animals:pig, sheep, duck, cow.
>
> Create another class called `AnimalTest` that reads the command line user input and creates the appropriate Animal child class based on the type of animal, and then calls the animal’s `sound()` method. Take some time to reflect on which class to create.

Do I write a test class that creates `Animal` child classes? How do you *create* animal classes from the Test Class? YouTube isn't too helpful on this.

This is my code:

PARENT CLASS

```java
public class Animal {
    void animal() {
        System.out.println("I am an animal");
    }
    public void sound() {
        System.out.println("An animal makes a sound based on the animal that it is.");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal mypig = new Animal();
        mypig.sound();
    }
}
```

ONE OF FOUR CHILD CLASSES (others basically repeats)

```java
public class cow extends Animal{
    public cow() {
        System.out.println("I am a cow");
    }
    public void sound() {
        System.out.println("cow says “moo”");
    }
}
```

MAIN CLASS

```java
public class Main {
    pig p = new pig();
    sheep s = new sheep();
    duck d = new duck();
    cow c = new cow();
}
```

ANIMAL TEST CLASS

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnimalTest {
    
    //create main class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //create scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get scanner input
        String input = scan.nextLine(); 
    }
}
```

I tried looking for test classes on YouTube but existing videos were only showing how to test existing classes.

Comment: You're doing exactly what you need to do in the `Main` class. Just check the input you're getting in `AnimalTest` and then instantiate one of those like you're doing in `Main` and call the `sound` method on the instances you create. For example `if (input.equals("cow")) { cow c = new cow(); c.sound(); }` As an aside, class names start with a capital letter, so `Pig`, `Sheep`, `Duck` and `Cow`.

Comment: `Animal animal; if (input.equals("cow")) { animal = new cow(); } else if ...` or `Animal animal = switch (input) { case "cow" -> new cow(); case ... }`; and either followed by `animal.sound();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnimalTest is just a name your professor recommmended for the class that holds the main method (I believe there might have been some confusion, as you might have thought it was a special class type).

So, your Animal Test class should look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnimalTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = null; // create an animal object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("pig")){ // assign a specific object instance based on the input
            animal = new Pig();
        }else if(input.equals("sheep")){
            animal = new Sheep();
        }else if(input.equals("cow")){
            animal = new Cow();
        }            
        animal.sound();       
    }
}
```

Your Animal class only needs the sound() method, which will be overrider by the child clases

```
class Animal {
    void sound(){
        System.out.println("Animal Sound");
    }    
}
```

Finally, your animal child classes should appear as follows (The @Override is an [java annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-override) utilized when replacing method implementation from parent clases).

```
class Pig extends Animal{
    @Override
    void sound (){
        System.out.println("Pig says oink !!");
    }
}
```

If you found this answer useful, consider marking it as the accepted answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much I get how to do it now: you're a lifesaver man